# Make a Bottom Navigation Views background transparent

Tags: android, androidx, bottomnavigationview

so I've added a bottom navigation view in my app but there,s a problem. I want my bottom navigation view's background to be transparent(it is currently black) i.e i want it to show the part of the background of the Relative layout (that contains the btmnav )that its covering .I've read somewhere that it does that by default and all i need to do is give the relative layout a background and it'll work...but when i do that, the background of the bottom navigation view remains black.

menu resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/live"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_live_tv_black_24dp"
    android:title="Live"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/squad"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_team_squad_black_24dp"
    android:title="Squad"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/schedule"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_schedule_black_24dp"
    android:title="Schedule"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/feed"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_rss_feed_black_24dp"
    android:title="Feed"/>

 </menu>
```

code in layout file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"


    >



     <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/btmnav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemTextColor="#fff3CD70"
    app:itemIconTint="#fff3CD70"


    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />



    </RelativeLayout>
```

[Before adding the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV54y.png)

[After adding the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Elq4h.png)

[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGhss.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the background of 'btmnav' to a color that has a transparent alpha channel.

Add to your BottonNavigationView
    android:background="#00ffffff"

You can also set a theme and set it there:

```
android:theme="@style/NavigationTheme"
```

Styles.xml

```
<style name="NavigationTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="itemIconTint">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="itemTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">#00ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Note: you should play with the alpha channel value to get the right level of transparency. 00 is fully transparent, but 30-50 will give a mostly transparent appearance, while aa-ff will be mostly opaque/

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this line:

```
BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.transparent));
```

This is my [project](https://github.com/kasimoz/Weather_Android)

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:** Create a drawable file with a transparent Rectangle

**res\drawable\transparent_rect.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#00000000" />
</shape>
```

**Step 2:**  Set the background of the `BottomNavigationView` to this drawable using `android:background`

```
android:background="@drawable/transparent_rect"
```